# JavaScript variable is undefined after being passed in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am working with a function and I just can't see what the problem is, help please?

This is the JavaScript function to check the length of an input.

```
function checkLength(o, min, max)
    {
        if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min )
        {
            $("#uper_length_stud").show()
            return false;
        } 
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

under it is a code which calls it.

```
$("#signin").click(function(e) {
       var name = $("#up_stud_fname").val(), x;
       x = checkLength(name, 3, 50);
       //other codes follow
}
```

It says at part o.val() that o is undefined. Though I think it is passed correctly? What seems to be the problem?

The Html part
    
        
    
    
    **NAME:**
    
        
        
        Update

Comment: because you have not passed any arguement in your function.

Comment: oh, sorry I was wrong with the question, I have edited it though..

Comment: Have you prefixed `some id about name` by a `#` ? The element exists ?

Comment: @PaoloLambojon. Do you mind add a console.log before you call checkLength function to see whether the name is properly returned by jquery? and you call val() twice, is it really expected based on your page?

Comment: @PaoloLambojon Post your html as well if possible, would be easier for us to help u:)

Comment: Probably you are looking something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441021/how-to-set-a-min-and-max-character-length-on-a-html-textbox-using-javascript

Comment: @PaulRad yes, it has a # since it is an id of a certain element..

Comment: @PandaZhang okay, I'll show you..

Comment: @PaulRad thank you. You were right all along. I have forgotten one element.

Answer (score 0):

In `checkLength()` you have not passed any thing.

Try to pass all arguments to it

Answer (score 0):

pass three parameters to the function

Here function wants 3 parameters ,and you are not passing it,so It says undefined

o, min, max

Answer (score 0):

Try this One
Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pratbhoir/9QTYk/

Html Code

```
<input id='firstName' />
<button id="btn"> Button</button>
```

JavaScript Code

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
    var name = $('#firstName').val();
    x = checkLength(name,1,4);
    //other codes follow
});


function checkLength(o, min, max)
{
    if ( o.length > max || o.length < min )
    {
        //$("#uper_length_stud").show()
        return false;
    } 
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can takeout the `.val()` from your if condition because `name` is a string which you are passing:

```
function checkLength(o, min, max){
    if ( o.length > max || o.length < min ){
        $("#uper_length_stud").show();
        return false;
    } 
}
```

and i think **you don't need the else** part and make sure that your function is in global scope.

Comment: I think you should add your html too and is your function is in global scope.